# Is "We decided to repeat the monologues in turn one after another" right?

Tags: sentence-construction

I was practicing English with a friend. The conversation we were working on was the monologues of a person on one end of the phone, we could not hear the voice of the other speaker. Therefore **We decided to repeat the monologues in turn one after another**.
Is this sentence right?

I mean to say the speaker in the audio said a sentence, we paused and one of us repeated. Then we resumed the track, the speaker said a sentence and this time the other of us repeated. How should I put this in a sentence?

Comment: It's more than a bit "tautological", given that *repeat, in turn, one after the other* are all just different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: I think the use of *therefore* is misleading or misplaced. As it stands *therefore* refers to the fact that your could not hear the voice of the other speaker and *that's why* (therefore) you decided...  But I think that's not what you intended.  And are these really monologues or are they just one side of a conversation?  I think I'd probably phrase it as, "We decided to take turns repeating lines from the conversation."

Comment: @Jim informative! They are just one side of  the conversation. by we could not hear I meant the sentences of the other side of the conversation was missing, they were not recorded. Please write an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It looks okay to me. However you can use the word 'both' in your sentence to make it more clear. Also by using comma at the end of your sentence.

> Therefore we *both* decided to repeat the monologues [in turn](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+turn), (one
>   after another.)

Or

> Therefore both of us decided to repeat the monologues in turn, (one after another.)

You will not need 'one after another' if you use 'both' because that would be pretty clear from 'in turn'.

Comment: How could I use the word *sentence* in **Therefore both of us decided to repeat the monologues in turn, (one after another.)**? I want to put an emphasis on that each of us repeated a sentence after the other had repeated the previous sentence. Ah, complicated!:(

Comment: I think this sentence would be fine for that. Although you can say: "Therefore both of us decided to repeat the sentences from the monologue in turn"

Comment: I agree that punctuation is the key issue here. Here's what would've been my suggestion: _We both decided to repeat the monologues – in turn, one after another_.

Answer (score 1):

"We chose to take turns, repeating one sentence [of the monologue] each."

This clarifies that the two of you alternated while repeating sentences from the monologue.

Answer (score 1):

*How should I put this sentence?*

It depends on how clear, precise, and complete you want to be. It also depends on whether you want a higher or better style, or whether your goal is to use language that is close to your original and you only want to make sure it is understandable. Finally, it also depends on whether or not you want to change some of the other sentences.

For example, do you want to make it easy for your reader or listener to understand the whole situation? I guess that the recording was made to help people learn or improve English. Is that correct?

I also guess that you are talking about an exercise in which learners are supposed to give the missing responses (the missing side of the conversation), but your friend and you decided to use a different way to practice: You listened to each sentence, paused the recording and then one of you would repeat what you heard. Then you resumed the recording to play the next sentence, paused it again, then the other of you repeated that one. And you continued taking turns in this way.

If this is all correct, then maybe one answer is something like: *We decided that one of us would repeat one sentence, the other of us the next, and so on.*